# Remote node IP is always changing in Monero Gui wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, remote-node

I want to use Monero Gui wallet 0.14.1.0 with remote node.
I trying to set daemon address opennode.xmr-tw.org:18089 or node.moneroworld.com:18089.
But it always changes to some unknown for me IP addresses...

So why remote node address always changes?
Is it safe to use those random daemon IP addresses instead of trusted opennode.xmr-tw.org:18089 or node.moneroworld.com:18089?

Comment: What IP address does it change to?

Comment: There are different IP addresses and they are always changing.

Comment: So, let's have some examples of those random addresses.

Answer (score 2):

In both `Simple mode` and `Simple mode (bootstrap)` the GUI will automatically connect to a random remote node. This configuration was preset by developers in order to improve user experience for the less technically inclined. This further means that, in both these modes, users cannot set a custom remote node. Whilst this may change in the future, users currently have to resort to `Advanced mode` in order to set their custom node. In `Advanced mode`, you can set the custom node on the `Settings` page. Switching to a different mode can be done as follows:

1. Go to the `Settings` page.
2. Close the current wallet.
3. In the wizard, select your desired mode.
4. Reopen the wallet via the `Open a wallet from file` option.

Comment: But is it safe to use those random remote nodes? I don't care about privacy and have very small amount of XMR. But I don't want my PC hacked.

Comment: A remote node cannot steal your funds. Besides, the nodes used for the GUI's `Simple mode` are the same that are used for `node.moneroworld.com`